# Avoiding Allocation with Diagonal Matrices in Eigen

Tags: c++, optimization, eigen, eigen3

### Question

How can I avoid dynamic allocation for small Diagonal Matrices in Eigen?

### Context

I'm using Eigen 3.4. I have a N by N Diagonal Matrix W:

```cpp
auto W = Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, Dynamic>(N);
```

I'd like to avoid allocation if N <= 512 by using a buffer on the stack:

```cpp
double W_buffer[512];
```

With normal vectors and matricies, I know I can use `Map`:

```cpp
double y_buff[512];
auto y = Eigen::Map<VectorXd>( y_buff, N );
```

However, when I try the same thing with a Diagonal Matrix, it gives me an error because `InnerStrideAtCompileTime` isn't a member of `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix`.

#### Error message when using Map with DiagonalMatrix

```
In file included from eigen/Eigen/Core:311,
                 from eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from build/release/CMakeFiles/bench.dir/cmake_pch.hxx:5,
                 from <command-line>:
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Map<Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, -1> > >’:
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:34:48:   required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::accessors_level<Eigen::Map<Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, -1> > >’
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:101:75:   required from ‘class Eigen::Map<Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, -1> >’
include/volar/estimators.hpp:203:18:   required from ‘static volar::R volar::PolyLE<Degree>::estimate(volar::R, volar::ViewR, volar::ViewR, const Kernel&) [with Kernel = volar::UniformK; int Degree = 1; volar::R = double; volar::ViewR = volar::View<double>]’
include/volar/kernel_smoothing.hpp:81:64:   required from ‘volar::R volar::LocalRFT<Estimator, Kernel>::operator()(volar::R) const [with Estimator = volar::EigenLinearLE; Kernel = volar::UniformK; volar::R = double]’
bench/core.cpp:43:23:   required from ‘void localRF(benchmark::State&) [with Method = volar::EigenLinearLE; Kernel = volar::UniformK]’
bench/core.cpp:96:1:   required from here
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:30:53: error: ‘InnerStrideAtCompileTime’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, -1>’
   30 |                              ? int(PlainObjectType::InnerStrideAtCompileTime)
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from eigen/Eigen/Core:163,
                 from eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from build/release/CMakeFiles/bench.dir/cmake_pch.hxx:5,
                 from <command-line>:
```

Answer (score 1):

The third template parameter of `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix`, `MaxSizeAtCompileTime` lets you do just that.

When combined with `Eigen::Dynamic`, the `DiagonalMatrix` will have an internal buffer large enough for `MaxSizeAtCompileTime`, but it will still be dynamically sized.

For example, the following is the equivalent of what you were trying to do with an external buffer:

```
auto W = Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 512>(N)
```

Obviously, attempting to initialize it with a size greater than  `MaxSizeAtCompileTime` will fail at runtime (with an assert), but that's not any worse than what you have to deal with when using `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to `Map` a `DiagonalMatrix` you can do it the "normal" way that you describe and use the `asDiagonal()` method.

Maybe slightly less clean to have to type `y.asDiagonal()` instead of just `y`...Maybe you could do something with `Eigen::Ref` to keep a reference to the diagonal matrix that came from your vector but I'm not sure if that would work.

`asDiagonal()`:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a14235b62c90f93fe910070b4743782d0